# How can I use a .ppk file for curl sftp file transfer?

Tags: curl, command-prompt

I'm trying to send a file transfer in windows using cURL, the command is stored as a batch file so i can schedule it when it works. I've generated a public and private key using putty. The private key is stored as a .ppk file and the public key has no file extension.

I've tried converting the file back into a regular private key using puttygen but no luck

```
C:\curl\bin\curl -T D:\myFile.csv -u myUsername: --key C:\keys\private-key.ppk  sftp://remote.site.com/incoming
```

When i run the command i get the following error message:
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Comment: "tried converting the file back into a regular private key using puttygen but no luck", the original question should be something about this "no luck".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the .ppk file to a mac machine and changed it to a private key file using the terminal.

```
puttygen private-key.ppk -O private-openssh -o private-key
```

I then altered the original curl command to the following:

```
C:\curl\bin\curl -v -k -T D:\myFile.csv --key C:\keys\private-key sftp://username:@remote.site.com/incoming/
```